# Elasticsearch docker version migration from 7.17.7 to 8.5.2 always CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

Small question regarding elasticsearch please.

I am currently using the version **7.17.7** of elasticsearch, found here https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch

I am deploying it using this manifest in Kubernetes, and no problem at all, everything is working fine, very happy.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elastic
spec:
  serviceName: elastic
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elastic
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elastic
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.7
#          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 1G
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 1G
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          env:
            - name: cluster.name
              value: mynamespace
            - name: node.name
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: "elastic-0.elasticsearch,elastic-1.elasticsearch,elastic-2.elasticsearch"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: "elastic-0,elastic-1,elastic-2"
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
        - name: increase-vm-max-map
          image: busybox
          command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        - name: increase-fd-ulimit
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: nfs-1
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 50Mi
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elastic
  labels:
    app: elastic
spec:
  selector:
    app: elastic
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
```

Now, I just want to bump the version up to **8.5.2**, literally just replacing this one line (the one commented out), leaving everything else exactly the same.

I then deploy this new version, and unfortunately, this happens.

```
NAME            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
pod/elastic-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (98s ago)    8m22s
pod/elastic-1   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (110s ago)   7m42s
pod/elastic-2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (76s ago)    7m38s

Containers:
  elastic:
    Container ID:   containerd://28100aa783d222c6899e82a6399d862bfc770ae096bbf338cb64183f7cc65026
    Image:          docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.2
    Image ID:       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:3464f7f6963c2b00a59a9efb2458949be35e56c22a8f0fd7c0ba8b028c96f5d8
    Ports:          9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    78
```

I am having a hard time understanding what I did wrong. I couldn't find anything useful regarding a migration.

When tailing the log, I do see:

```
2022-12-06 07:12:44,449 process reaper (pid 86) ERROR Recursive call to appender rolling
{"@timestamp":"2022-12-06T07:12:44.250Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"uncaught exception in thread [process reaper (pid 86)]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"process reaper (pid 86)","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler","elasticsearch.node.name":"elastic-0","error.type":"java.security.AccessControlException","error.message":"access denied (\"java.lang.RuntimePermission\" \"modifyThread\")","error.stack_trace":"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (\"java.lang.RuntimePermission\" \"modifyThread\")\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:485)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1068)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.securesm@8.5.2/org.elasticsearch.secure_sm.SecureSM.checkThreadAccess(SecureSM.java:166)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.securesm@8.5.2/org.elasticsearch.secure_sm.SecureSM.checkAccess(SecureSM.java:120)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.checkAccess(Thread.java:2360)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(Thread.java:2308)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ProcessHandleImpl.lambda$static$0(ProcessHandleImpl.java:103)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:928)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:186)\n"}
```

May I ask what is going on please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docker.html) says Starting in Elasticsearch 8.0, security is enabled by default. With security enabled, Elastic Stack security features require TLS encryption for the transport networking layer, or your cluster will fail to start please check it.

Elastic search has made some changes for 8.5 you can check them in this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/migrating-8.0.html).
If you are using java_home upgrade it to Java 17 which is needed for the 8.5 version.

Try to get that image's Dockerfile, update the versions installed in it, and re-run docker build to update it, Attaching the latest version for [installing elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/docker.html) with docker

Attaching a similar [issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-properly-upgrade-elasticsearch-running-as-docker-containers/221711) asked in the elastic search community.